# PostgreSQL: row_to_json with selective columns

Tags: json, postgresql, row, postgresql-9.4

**Task concept and my question**

Using Postgres 9.4. How could I use `row_to_json(row)` with selective columns (not the entire row)? I need to discard one column from the row constructor while building JSON, but also need to preserve column names.

**Restrictions**

1. Do not use self join to the same table/cte with selective columns choice
2. Do not use external function to handle deleting key from json, afterwards

I'm well aware that I can write and use my own function to remove a key from JSON, or that in Postgres 9.5 there is `-` operator for JSONB. However, I would like to do this beforehand without additional function call and I'm pretty sure it's possible.

**MVCE and explanation**

Generating sample data

```
CREATE TABLE test_table ( id int, col1 int, col2 int, col3 text );
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES 
  (1, 23, 15, 'Jessica'), (2, 43, 84, 'Thomas');
```

1) First try, simple `row_to_json(row)`, which is obviously not working:

```
SELECT id, row_to_json(t) FROM test_table t
```

I need to discard column `id` from the row constructor not to add it while parsing the row as json. Above returns:

```
 id |                  row_to_json
----+-----------------------------------------------
  1 | {"id":1,"col1":23,"col2":15,"col3":"Jessica"}
  2 | {"id":2,"col1":43,"col2":84,"col3":"Thomas"}
```

2) Second try, with explicit passing of columns `row_to_json(row(col1, ...))`:

```
SELECT id, row_to_json(row(col1, col2, col3)) FROM test_table t
```

But I'm losing column names (as mentioned in docs it all converts to `fX`, where X is a number:

```
 id |           row_to_json
----+----------------------------------
  1 | {"f1":23,"f2":15,"f3":"Jessica"}
  2 | {"f1":43,"f2":84,"f3":"Thomas"}
```

**Expected output**

Expected output is obviously from the (1) point in MVCE but without `id` key-value pair:

```
 id |                  row_to_json
----+-----------------------------------------------
  1 | {"col1":23,"col2":15,"col3":"Jessica"}
  2 | {"col1":43,"col2":84,"col3":"Thomas"}
```

Comment: `json_build_object('col1', col1, 'col2', col2, 'col3', col3)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm aware of that, thanks, but I'd rather not type it all manually - my real case scenario has around 100 columns :-)

Comment: Sounds like a good reason to upgrade ;)

Comment: @pozs thank you :-) I somehow missed that one during searching. I've marked the question as duplicate.

Comment: ```SELECT id, row_to_json(t)::jsonb-'id' FROM test_table t```
Starting with v10 in postgresql you can delete a key value from the left operand, which will return exactly your required result.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that creating a type with desired column names and matching data types and then casting the row to it will do the trick:

```
CREATE TYPE my_type AS (
  col1 int,
  col2 int,
  col3 text
);
```

Then altering my statement by adding the cast of row to defined type:

```
SELECT id, row_to_json(cast(row(col1, col2, col3) as my_type)) FROM test_table t;
```

Brings out the expected output:

```
 id |                  row_to_json
----+-----------------------------------------------
  1 | {"col1":23,"col2":15,"col3":"Jessica"}
  2 | {"col1":43,"col2":84,"col3":"Thomas"}
```

However, is there any method for this to be built without additional type?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This I believe would add additional step to the solution, since `json_populate_record` takes JSON as an argument.

Comment: ```SELECT id, row_to_json(t)::jsonb-'id' FROM test_table t```
Starting with v10 in postgresql you can delete a key value from the left operand, which will return exactly your required result.